# Is there a way to flush stdout on process termination for parallel processes

Tags: bash, shell, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, flush

I'm running several independent programs on a single machine in parallel.
The processes (say 100) are all relatively short (<5 minutes) and their output is limited to a few hundred lines (~kilobytes).

Usually the output in a terminal then becomes mangled because the processes write directly to the same buffer. I would like these outputs to be un-mangled so that it's easier to debug certain processes. I could write these outputs to temporary files but I would like to limit disk IO and would prefer another method if possible. It would require cleaning up and probably won't really improve code readability.

Is there any shell native method that allows buffers to be PID separated which then flushes to stdout/stderr when the process terminates ? Do you see any other way to do this ?

**Update**

I ended up using the `tail -n 1000000` trick from the comment of @Gem. Since the commands I'm using are long and (covering multiple lines) and I was already using subshells `( ... ) &` that was a quite minimal change from `( ... ) &` to  `( ... ) 2>&1 | tail -n 1000000 &`.

Comment: One quick trick I have used in the past is to pipe to `tail -n 1000000` in order to buffer up all the output and print it in one go - `tail` is forced to buffer up all the output because it doesn't know if it might in fact be 1000001 lines long. There is still a chance that two jobs will end at the same time, but I find it helps quite a bit.

Comment: @mark-setchell I ended up using the `tail -n 1000000` trick that @Gem-taylor provided above. Since the commands I'm using are long and (covering multiple lines) and I was already using subshells `( ... ) &` that was a quite minimal change from `( ... ) &` to  `( ... ) 2>&1 | tail -n 1000000 &`. If you could repost that as a solution I'll accept it as solving

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with **GNU Parallel**. Use `-k` to keep the output in order and `:::` to separate the arguments you want passed to your program.

Here we run 4 instances of `echo` in parallel:

```
parallel -k echo {} ::: {0..4}
0
1
2
3
4
```

Now add in `--tag` to tag your output lines with the filenames or parameters you are using:

```
parallel --tag -k 'echo "Line 1, param {}"; echo "Line 2, param {}"' ::: {1..4}
1   Line 1, param 1
1   Line 2, param 1
2   Line 1, param 2
2   Line 2, param 2
3   Line 1, param 3
3   Line 2, param 3
4   Line 1, param 4
4   Line 2, param 4
```

You should notice that each line is tagged on the left side with the parameters and that the two lines from each job are kept together.

---

You can now specify how your output is organised.

- Use `--group` to group output by job
- Use `--line-buffer` to buffer a line at a time
- Use `--ungroup` if you want output all mixed up, but as soon as available

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just want [syslog](https://linux.die.net/man/8/rsyslogd), or rather [logger](https://linux.die.net/man/1/logger) its Bash interface. Example:

```
echo "Something happened!" | logger -i -p local0.notice
```

If you insist on getting output to stderr *too* use `--stderr`. `rsyslog` will handle buffering, atomic writes, etc, and is presumably pretty good at optimizing disk I/O. However you could also easily configure rsyslog to route the log facility (i.e. local0 or what ever you choose to use) where ever you want, such as on a tmpfs or dedicated disk, or even over TCP. See [/etc/rsyslog.conf](https://linux.die.net/man/5/rsyslog.conf).